# Corona: trigger sprite on touch

Tags: lua, touch, coronasdk, sprite

I'd like to trigger a sprite animation when it is touched, and only have it loop once.

I have a sprite animation that currently triggers on screen touch, but I don't know how to make it so it only animates when the sprite itself is touched.

```
require "sprite"

local sheet1 = sprite.newSpriteSheet( "greenman.png", 75, 105 )

local spriteSet1 = sprite.newSpriteSet(sheet1, 1, 16)

sprite.add( spriteSet1, "green", 1, 12, 700, 1 ) -- play 12 frames every 700 ms
local instance1 = sprite.newSprite( spriteSet1 )
instance1.x = display.contentWidth/2
instance1.y = display.contentHeight/2.8

function kick( event )
  if(event.phase == "ended") then
    instance1:prepare("green")
    instance1:play()
  end
end

Runtime:addEventListener("touch", kick)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use an anonymous function for one-time code
where you would code once and forget later:

```
instance1:addEventListener("touch", function(event)
  if(event.phase == "ended") then
    instance1:prepare("green")
    instance1:play()
  end
end)
```

---

do this when you want the function to be tied to the object,
and it may morph for different instances,
save the `kick` function under `instance1` as one of its properties,
then add/remove it:

```
instance1.kick=function(event)
  if(event.phase == "ended") then
    instance1:prepare("green")
    instance1:play()
  end
end

instance1:addEventListener("touch",instance1.kick)
```

---

If the event handler is shared across different objects and used widely:

```
function kick( event )
  if(event.phase == "ended") then
    instance1:prepare("green")
    instance1:play()
  end
end

instance1:addEventListener("touch", kick)
```

Answer (score 1):

please try

```
instance1:addEventListener( "touch" , kick )
```

or even

```
instance1:addEventListener( "tap" , kick )
```

Answer (score 0):

just write:

```
instance1:addEventListener ("touch", kick)
```

instead of:

```
Runtime:addEventListener ("touch", kick)
```